# XSLT date format translation from eg: Aug 23 2018 to 23/08/2018

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, date-format

How to do date format translation from e.g: `Aug 23 2018` to `23/08/2018` using XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0** does not have any `date` functions and you will need to use `string` manipulation functions to convert from one format to another and translate `Aug` to `08` using some processing logic.

**XSLT 2.0** does have `format-date()` function however the input format expected by this function is `YYYY-MM-DD` which can then be converted into formats shown in these [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples).

You can use the below options for converting the date format

Input XML

```
<inputDate>Aug 23 2018</inputDate>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="inputDate">
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring(., 5, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="mth" select="substring(., 1, 3)" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring(., 8, 4)" />

    <!-- Convert 3 char month name to digit -->
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mth)) div 3 + 1" />
    <!-- Format the number to 2 digits -->
    <xsl:variable name="mthNum" select="format-number($month, '00')" />

    <formattedDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($day,'/',$mthNum,'/',$year)" />
    </formattedDate>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

Here the solution has used `regex` to match with the input date format. You can use a different approach as well.

```
<xsl:template match="inputDate">
    <!-- Define array of months -->
    <xsl:variable name="months" select="('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')" />
    <!-- Define regex to match input date format -->        
    <xsl:analyze-string regex="^(([A-Za-z]{{3}}) (\d\d) (\d\d\d\d))$" select=".">
        <!-- Align the regex groups according to the output format -->
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <formattedDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)" />
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(index-of($months, regex-group(2)), '00')" />
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)" />
            </formattedDate>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Output from both these templates

```
<formattedDate>23/08/2018</formattedDate>
```