# Convert date format from YYYY-MM-DD (2018-08-21) to MMM-DD-YYY (Aug-21-2018)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Looking to see how I can convert the following date format using xsl 1.0:

YYYY-MM-DD
to
MMM-DD-YYY

For example:
2018-08-21
to
Aug-21-2018

Thank you!!

Comment: So which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly do you use? Have you checked whether it allows to call/use extension in e.g. Java or C# or whatever programming language or framework it interfaces with to solve that task? Or what have you tried in XSLT to reorder the components of the input format and convert one component from a number to a string?

Comment: Please check the solution for a similar question. This may help you in coming up with your solution. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767550/xslt-date-format-translation-from-eg-aug-23-2018-to-23-08-2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767550/xslt-date-format-translation-from-eg-aug-23-2018-to-23-08-2018)

Comment: Simplest solutions are either (a) upgrade to XSLT 2.0 and use format-date(), or (b) install the EXSLT date-time library for your selected XSLT processor if available.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier in **XSLT 2.0** or greater using [`format-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-date):

```
format-date(xs:date('2018-08-21'), '[MNn,*-3]-[D]-[Y]')
```

The **XSLT 1.0** solution below uses [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring) to identify the date components, a named template with a parameter to translate the month number into an abbreviation, and then [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat) to generate the final result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="MMM-DD-YYY">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="'2018-08-21'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="MMM-DD-YYY">
        <xsl:param name="date"/>

        <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1,4)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="month">
            <xsl:call-template name="month-abbr">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="number(substring($date, 6, 2))"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="concat($month,'-',$day,'-',$year)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="month-abbr">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 1">Jan</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 2">Feb</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 3">Mar</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 4">Apr</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 5">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 6">Jun</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 7">Jul</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 8">Aug</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 9">Sep</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 10">Oct</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 11">Nov</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month = 12">Dec</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```